# SSHD, NTPD slow to respond

Tags: ssh, ntp, latency, ntpd

My server has been responding very slowly ever since I put it into production, however it's not slow how you might think. When I SSH to the physical virtualization server I receive the typical `login as:` prompt. When I type my UN in, it takes and sits idly for about 45-60 seconds, then produces the banner, and password prompt. Once I input my password, everything is fine (no latent responses). The reason I'm asking about this is because I'm runnning NTP and TACACS+ on physical host in different virtual servers and when I try to sync anything to NTP I have a similar result the client times out while syncing.

Pings are successful with an average latency of <10MS, but all other network applications are very slow. I was not sure what information I should provide, but I'll happily provide anything you ask for within reason.

Comment: Do you connect on hostname or ip address? Could it be DNS related?

Comment: No DNS for that subnet. I only connect via a RFC1918 address, without NAT. Statically routed from my office to that subnet.

Answer (score 3):

Simple `UseDNS no` in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` fixed my issue for SSH, now to implement it on all my vHosts and see if NTP is fixed. With this my banner showed up immediately, but the password prompt was still slow. Since I have no DNS I removed the hostname from `/etc/hostname` and ran `hostname localhost.localdomain` and the password prompt now shows up immediately.